# Trying to delete a directory and his hidden files in linux with php

Tags: php, linux, filesystems

From the command line when I use:

```
rm -fr /path/dir/{*,.??*}
```

I can delete all files in `/path/dir` including the hidden files, but when I try to make this from PHP with this code:

`system('rm -fr /path/dir/{*,.??*}')` nothing happens.

I can't find why this doesn't works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally with this:

```
system('rm -fr /path/dir && mkdir /path/dir);
```

I removed the directory with all his files and after I created the directory. And the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want delete the directory itself, so you don't have to recreate it. This will delete all contents of directory including hidden files without warning msg.

```
rm -rf ..?* .[!.]* *
```